# Пропадает текст в командной строке как только появляется новый. Можно ли исправить?

Tags: c#

Я писал код чтобы увидеть весь огромный результат, который я запланировал увидеть. Я писал код на языке C# в Visual Studio. После запуска появляется командная строка, отрабатывает и когда останавливается остаётся только результат последних нескольких секунд. Мне нужно чтобы он был виден целиком. Что делать?

Comment: может вам просто не в консоль все выводить а в файл?

Comment: Было бы неплохо, только я не знаю как так сделать. Буду очень благодарен Вам, если поможете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У консоли ограничена высота буфера (как и ширина), посмотреть и поменять ее можно через `Console.BufferHeight`. Если количество строк в выводе превышает `Console.BufferHeight`, то старые строки стираются.

Вам нужно либо увеличить высоту буфера консоли, либо писать свои результаты в файл.
Последнее предпочтительнее и безопаснее. Даже если вы зададите огромный буфер, он кстати скушает много оперативы, нет гарантий, что вывод точно не будет больше.

Comment: Я понял как работать с высотой буфера обмена, но не могли бы Вы подсказать как записать всё в файл? Буду очень признателен!

Comment: @GopPog Самое простое - создайте `var sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt");`, пишите в него так же как в консоль `sw.WriteLine(что-то там);` после записи закройте файл `sw.Close();` или `sw.Dispose()`, без разницы.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! У меня всё получилось!